# Nhibernate where substring error

Tags: nhibernate, substring, queryover

I have a working query like this:

```
SELECT this_.ID, this_.NomeFile, this_.DataGenerazioneFile, esitiopera_.ID, esitiopera_.Date, esitiopera_.ID_FileTelematico
FROM FileTelematico this_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EsitoOperazione esitiopera_ ON this_.ID = esitiopera_.ID_FileTelematico 
WHERE SUBSTRING (this_.NomeFile, 1, LEN(this_.NomeFile)-4)
IN ('filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3')   
ORDER BY this_.DataGenerazioneFile DESC;
```

and I'm trying to write the same with QueryOver

```
FileTelematico ft = null;
string[] nomi = {'filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3'}
var files = session.QueryOver<FileTelematico>(() => ft)                     
            .Where(() => ft.NomeFile.Substr(1, ft.NomeFile.StrLength() -4)
            .IsIn(nomi))
            .Fetch(x => x.EsitiOperazioni).Eager
            .OrderBy(() => ft.DataGenerazioneFile).Desc
            .List()
```

but it just end with a System.NullReferenceException

```
    in System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   in System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   in System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   in System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   in NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.FindValue(Expression expression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:riga 248
   in NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(Expression expression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:riga 258
   in NHibernate.Criterion.RestrictionExtensions.ProcessIsInCollection(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Criterion\RestrictionsExtensions.cs:riga 138
   in NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessCustomMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:riga 662
   in NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessBooleanExpression(Expression expression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:riga 620
   in NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessExpression(Expression expression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:riga 671
   in NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessLambdaExpression(LambdaExpression expression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:riga 676
   in NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessExpression(Expression`1 expression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:riga 697
   in NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.Add(Expression`1 expression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Criterion\QueryOver.cs:riga 755
   in NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.Where(Expression`1 expression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Criterion\QueryOver.cs:riga 362
   in NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.NHibernate.IQueryOver<TRoot,TSubType>.Where(Expression`1 expression) in d:\Projects\NHibernate\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Criterion\QueryOver.cs:riga 803
   in
```

this will not happen if I don't use Substr but I need to use it (or Substring).

P.S. I'm using Nhibernate 4.0.3 GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `.SubStr` extension method is not powerful enough to handle anything but constant values as arguments.

Luckily, you can get around this by using `Projections.SqlFunction` and calling the `substring` method that way instead. You'll also need to add a function that can do subtraction, since unfortunately you can't do arithmetic operations with built-in QueryOver functionality.

First, create a static class that contains your custom projections:

```
public static class CustomProjections
{
    public static IProjection Subtract(IProjection one, IProjection other)
    {
        return Projections.SqlFunction(
            new VarArgsSQLFunction(NHibernateUtil.Int32, "(", "-", ")"),
            NHibernateUtil.Int32,
            one,
            other);
    }

    public static IProjection SubStr(IProjection prop, IProjection start, IProjection end)
    {
        return Projections.SqlFunction(
            "substring",
            NHibernateUtil.String,
            prop,
            start,
            end);
    }

    public static IProjection Length(IProjection prop)
    {
        return Projections.SqlFunction(
            "length",
            NHibernateUtil.Int32,
            prop);
    }
}
```

Next, use `Restrictions.In` and use the custom projections, passing the result of the `Length` projection to `SubStr`:

```
FileTelematico ft = null;

session.QueryOver<FileTelematico>(() => ft)
    .Where(
        Restrictions.In(
            CustomProjections.SubStr(
                Projections.Property(() => ft.NomeFile),
                Projections.Constant(1),
                CustomProjections.Subtract(
                    CustomProjections.Length(
                        Projections.Property(() => ft.NomeFile)),
                        Projections.Constant(4))),
            nomi))
    .Fetch(x => x.EsitiOperazioni).Eager
    .OrderBy(() => ft.DataGenerazioneFile).Desc
    .List();
```

Kind of messy, but should get the job done.

You can clean this up a little if you want to by refactoring the various parts of the `.Where` call into variables:

```
FileTelematico ft = null;

IProjection length = 
    CustomProjections.Subtract(
        CustomProjections.Length(Projections.Property(() => ft.NomeFile)),
        Projections.Constant(4));

IProjection substring =
    CustomProjections.SubStr(
        Projections.Property(() => ft.NomeFile),
        Projections.Constant(1),
        length);

AbstractCriterion inRestriction =
    Restrictions.In(substring, nomi);


session.QueryOver<FileTelematico>(() => ft)
    .Where(inRestriction)
    .Fetch(x => x.EsitiOperazioni).Eager
    .OrderBy(() => ft.DataGenerazioneFile).Desc
    .List();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it write the correct SQL but if I can't use this:
`LEN(this_.NomeFile) - 4`
and seems that this is not possibile, there is no use of such query.

Comment: @Shyguy: I'm so sorry, I completely missed the `- 4` part. I'll fix that and update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this produce the correct SQL and I've learn a new workaround in case of future need.